Rate limitations and slash commands with Discord API (discord.py)
I've been encountering an issue recently- specifically with slash commands. Both with syncing them and actually using them.
So, as I understand it, whenever you make requests to the Discord API, you run the risk of being rate limited (with things like syncing command trees), where your terminal will spit out something along the lines of 'Warning: you are being rate limited, trying again in xxx. I've had this pop up occasionally, but recently my code has been 'hanging', and I'm unable to catch any errors or exceptions because no output is being produced when this happens.
Here is the relevant code, the first section is the command syncing, which, even though I'm suspecting is encountering rate limiting, doesn't actually output anything to the terminal. - as seen by the output, which spits out the logging, but then hangs for a solid few minutes, even though I'm only syncing 3 commands. Again, it does this sometimes, and other times it's almost instantaneous.
The second section is the error I get when using a normal slash command (that I've confirmed has been synced) where I get a vague error in Discord, and nothing within the terminal.
Code (syncing slash command):
    @discord.app_commands.command()
    async def reload(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, extension: str = None):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        print('reload command used')
        self.logger.info(f"Reload command triggered with extension: {extension}")

        if not os.path.isdir(self.ext_dir):
            self.logger.error(f"Extension directory {self.ext_dir} does not exist.")
            return

        if extension is not None and extension != 'cogmgr':
            try:
                await self.bot.unload_extension(f'{self.ext_dir}.{extension}')
                self.logger.info(f'Unloaded extension {extension}')
                await self.bot.load_extension(f'{self.ext_dir}.{extension}')
                self.logger.info(f'Loaded extension {extension}')
            except commands.ExtensionError:
                self.logger.error(f'Failed to load extension {extension}\n{traceback.format_exc()}')
        else:
            for filename in os.listdir(self.ext_dir):
                if filename.endswith('.py') and not filename.startswith('_') and not filename == 'cogmgr':
                    try:
                        await self.bot.unload_extension(f'{self.ext_dir}.{filename[:-3]}')
                        self.logger.info(f'Unloaded extension {filename[:-3]}')
                        await self.bot.load_extension(f'{self.ext_dir}.{filename[:-3]}')
                        self.logger.info(f'Loaded extension {filename[:-3]}')
                    except commands.ExtensionError:
                        self.logger.error(f'Failed to load extension {filename[:-3]}\n{traceback.format_exc()}')
        await interaction.followup.send(f'Reloaded {extension if extension is not None else 'all extensions'}')


Output (this example shows a minute or two of delay, but it can, and has taken up to five before):

[2024-12-12 09:22:17,192] INFO: Syncing commands with Discord...
[2024-12-12 09:22:19,590] INFO: Syncing commands with Discord...
[2024-12-12 09:22:23,551] INFO: Syncing commands with Discord...
[2024-12-12 09:23:15,350] INFO: Successfully synced commands.
[2024-12-12 09:23:15,873] INFO: Successfully synced commands.



Code (normal slash command):
    @discord.app_commands.command()
    async def container(self, interaction:discord.Integration, container:str):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        print(container)

        content = self.container_request(container)
        print(content)

        if content is None:
            if self.result_un.status_code == 200:

                #call successful, container not found
                self.logger.info(f'Status code: {self.result_un.status_code} container-visit call successfully sent, however container was not found in the Port Connect database\ncheck for typos')
                #await interaction.followup.send(f'Call Error: The container was not found in the Port Connect database, but the call was successful\nStatus code: {self.result_un.status_code}')
            else:

                self.logger.error(f'Status code: {self.result_un.status_code} container-visit call was not successful')
                #await interaction.followup.send(f'Call Error: The call was unsuccessful\nStatus code: {self.result_un.status_code}')

            return

        self.logger.info(f'Status code: {self.result_un.status_code} container-visit call successfully sent, data returned')

        embed = discord.Embed(title=content['container'])
        embed.set_author(name='Port Bot')

        keys = list (content.keys())

        for i in range(len(keys)):

            key = keys[i]
            value = content[key]

            embed.add_field(name=key, value=value, inline=False)
       
        await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed)


async def setup(bot):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s")
    await bot.add_cog(Containerhandler(bot))


output (from discord):

portbot APP — Yesterday at 16:16
Unknown Integration
Only you can see this • Dismiss message

Ultimately, my questions are, does rate limiting apply to the usage of syncing, and using commands, and how do you actually catch it - the HTTP exception I have there doesn't seem to be catching anything. Additionally, what does 'unkown integration' mean in this context within Discord?
I'm aware the code doesn't adhere to pep8, I'm working across three monitors and have an abundance of space for long lines. Please don't hate me

No one will "hate you" for not formatting code correctly (unless it's an employer or something). You can read up here on rate limiting.
To answer your questions, rate limiting applies to all requests, with the limit being around 50 requests per second for most endpoints. There's also a separate limit for invalid requests.
To actually catch the error, you could use HTTP handling, as rate limiting returns an HTTP 429 response. Looking at your code, your syncing seems to be a command itself. Something like this should suffice:
@bot.event #Should be self explanatory
async def on_command_error(ctx, error): #Should be self explanatory
    if isinstance(error, discord.HTTPException): #See if the error is from discord's HTTP exceptions
        if error.status == 429: #Check error code for rate limiting
            print("Rate limited!") # Do whatever you want

Additionally to your Unknown Integration issue, it seems this may be the cause (read the last 3 comments). My guess (but just my guess) is you do something to your commands when you "sync" your commands that causes them to get new ids.
Even though the official Discord API is in a different programming language, Discord.py is an API wrapper for that, and so will definitely encounter many of the same issues. However, this would be a different issue and you would need to do more research and digging through your code to figure out where this issue happens.
